# WD hard drive for Mac Apple to read in Windows OS

Tags: mac, hard-drive

Help!
Is there any possible way that I can read my files on a WD hard drive on a Windows computer without reformatting the hard drive?
Because I know it is needed to reformat the hard drive before using it on a Windows computer. Is there any way to open my files on a WD hard drive and make the disk readable in any Windows computer without reformatting, since I can't use my MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 5):

There are several apps that allow you to either read-only or read/write to HFS+ partitions, which are used in MacOS.

- [HFS Explorer](http://www.catacombae.org/hfsexplorer/), read-only, free
- [Paragon HFS](https://backstage.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/), read/write, 10 day trial, after that ~20€
- [Mediafour MacDrive](http://www.mediafour.com/software/macdrive/), read/write, 5 day trial, after that ~50€

Answer (score -1):

You could light up a [VirtualBox VM with Sierra](https://www.howtogeek.com/289594/how-to-install-macos-sierra-in-virtualbox-on-windows-10/) then attach then attach the USB drive to the VM.  macOS would then be able to natively read and write the drive allowing you to get the files off for you to work with.

If there's no data on the drive, then just format in Windows as FAT32. It will be compatible with both Windows and Mac